# Mongoose Populate return null when the reference is put in sub-schema

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 3 schemas
1. User
2. SignedToEvent
3. Events

The User contains information about user and has a relation to SignedToEvents. The SignedToEvents couples the user to an event.
The SignedToEvent is nested within User like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SignedToEvents = new Schema({
    event : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'event' },
    eventSignedDate: {type : Date, default : Date.now()},
    isActive : Boolean
})

SignedToEvents.set('toObject', { getters: true });
SignedToEvents.set('toJSON', { getters: true });

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    password : String,
    age : Number,
    sex : String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    signedToEvents : [SignedToEvents]
})

UserSchema.set('toObject', { getters: true });
UserSchema.set('toJSON', { getters: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema, 'users');
```

And the event schema looks like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const eventSchema = new Schema({
    shortId : String,
    name: String,
    description : String,
    organization : String
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('event', eventSchema, 'events');
```

In my API I have a call to the User collection:

```
User.findOne({_id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.userId)})
    .select("email")
    .populate("event")
    .exec()
    .then(docs=>{
        console.log(docs)
        res.status(200).send(docs.signedToEvents)
    });
```

Now, my hopes was to get an aggregated collection of User, SignedToEvent and Event. However thats not the case.

It only returns users id and email.

/Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to point to my signedToEvent property and then use .event to reach the event model. Like this:

```
User.findOne({_id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.userId)})
    .select("email")
    .populate("signedToEvents.event")
    .exec()
    .then(docs=>{
        console.log(docs)
        res.status(200).send(docs.signedToEvents)
    });
```